# how to display progress bar while reading object from input stream?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

i am downloading a file from server and files is downloaded successfully now i want to display downloading progress via progress bar. My code is below>>

```
private ObjectInputStream in;
in=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Data  data1 = (Data) in.readObject();
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\jabir\\Desktop\\"+data1.getName());


fos.write(data1.getFile());
```

Comment: Yes there is. See `javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream`. @Cubic

Comment: @EJP that might actually be what the asker wanted, hence I rescinded the comment, but it's not how I understood the question.  `ProgressMonitorInputStream` didn't know how much work is left either, it's only meant to communicate that a long running task is happening and provides a way to interrupt it.

Comment: @Cubic That's not correct either. It provides access to the underlying `ProgressMonitor`, which in turn provides a `setMaximum()` method, for the cases when you know it.

Comment: @EJP That 'when you know it' part is what I'm referring to. I think the asker is more likely struggling with getting the progress information than displaying a bar.

Comment: @Cubic Nothing about that in the question. You're guessing. It isn't up to us to guess, or to provide false information based on our guesses. If you want clarification from the OP, ask for it,